# Paperclips: Unspecified errorUnable to layout page

Tags: java

We have old legacy code with the antique library "Paperclips" and there is a problem with how the columns of a `GridPrint` are created. The following standalone class shows the exception:

```
public class TableControlPrintBigColumnsTest {

    private final static int MAX_WIDTH = 567; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shell shell = new Shell();
        TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.NONE);
        tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
        createColumn(tableViewer, "A", 5000);
        createColumn(tableViewer, "B", 600);
        createColumn(tableViewer, "C", 70);
        tableViewer.setInput(Arrays.asList("Hallo World!"));

        GridPrint print = createPrint(tableViewer.getTable());
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog(shell, SWT.NONE);
        PrinterData printerData = dialog.open();
        if (printerData != null) {
            PaperClips.print(new PrintJob("Print Job", new ScalePrint(print)), printerData);
        }
    }

    private static void createColumn(TableViewer tableViewer, String text, int width) {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(tableViewer.getTable(), SWT.LEFT);
        column.setText(text);
        column.setWidth(width);
    }

    public static GridPrint createPrint(Table table) {
        DefaultGridLook look = new DefaultGridLook();
        GridPrint gridPrint = new GridPrint(look);

        TableColumn[] columns = table.getColumns();
        int[] columnSizes = calculateColumnSizes(columns);
        TableItem[] items = table.getItems();

        // create header
        for (int col = 0; col < columns.length; col++) {
            TableColumn column = columns[col];
            gridPrint.addColumn(new GridColumn(column.getAlignment(), columnSizes[col], 1));
            gridPrint.addHeader(new TextPrint(column.getText(), SWT.CENTER));
        }

        // create individual cells
        for (int row = 0; row < items.length; row++) {
            TableItem item = items[row];
            for (int col = 0; col < columns.length; col++) {
                gridPrint.add(new TextPrint(item.getText(col), columns[col].getAlignment()));
            }
        }
        return gridPrint;
    }

    private static int[] calculateColumnSizes(TableColumn[] columns) {
        int[] columnSizes = Arrays.stream(columns).mapToInt(c -> c.getWidth()).toArray();
        normalize(columnSizes);
        return columnSizes;
    }

    private static void normalize(int[] columnSizes) {
        if (Arrays.stream(columnSizes).sum() > MAX_WIDTH) {
            int width = Arrays.stream(columnSizes).sum();
            double ratio = (double) width / MAX_WIDTH;
            for (int i = 0; i < columnSizes.length; i++) {
                columnSizes[i] = (int) (columnSizes[i] / ratio);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this code, it will lead to the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Unspecified errorUnable to layout page 1
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4308)
    at net.sf.paperclips.PaperClips.error(PaperClips.java:82)
    at net.sf.paperclips.PaperClips.error(PaperClips.java:70)
    at net.sf.paperclips.PaperClips.getPages(PaperClips.java:422)
    at net.sf.paperclips.PaperClips.print(PaperClips.java:255)
    at net.sf.paperclips.PaperClips.print(PaperClips.java:210)
    at net.sf.paperclips.PaperClips.print(PaperClips.java:186)
    at TableControlPrintBigColumnsTest.main(TableControlPrintBigColumnsTest.java:39)
```

The crux of the problem is the `normalize(int[])` method. Without it, the `GridPrint` will be as giant as the table - over 5000 pixel in this case. Since the table is scaled done with the `ScalePrint`, it does work without exception, but the scaling makes the font in the table too tiny to read. If I omit the `ScalePrint`, the same exception is thrown (because the table is to big for the page.

So what I assume happens is that even though the 3rd column is only 7pixel width after the normalizing, it gets stretched to the size of the biggest item in the list and so the table is bigger than the page again.

I can fix this by wrapping the `TextPrint` in `ScalePrint`, but that makes the column entirely unreadable. I'd much prefer to show only the first couple of chars and cut the rest of the text off.

Is there a print I could use? Is there any way to get the size of a font so I can snip the `TextPrint`'s text myself?